# Why does the body not develop immunity to rabies during the period of incubation?

Tags: virology, rabies

Rabies typically has an incubation period of 20 to 60 days and most cases develop only after at least a month after the bite from the infected animal.

Nevertheless, rabies is nearly always fatal and the host seems to consistently fail to develop an effective immune response to the virus, even though it has been exposed to the virus for weeks or even months.

It generally is supposed that an immune response takes about 10-14 days to develop. In other words, if the body is presented with a novel viral pathogen, it takes 10-14 for the body to recognize the pathogen and begin making antibodies to defend against it. However, this does not seem to hold true in the case of rabies, which can be present and motive in the body for many weeks before causing fatal infection, yet the body still fails to mount an immune defense. Why is this?

Comment: I hate to ask, but what did you find on searching for an answer? There's a very simple reason that it's not like a lot of other viruses in terms of exposure and development of immunity. Incidentally, there are people in areas of high incidence of rabies who have developed antibodies without known exposure. The mechanism for this is unclear.

Comment: @anongoodnurse My research was to read the chapter on Rhabdoviruses and specifically the Lyssaviridae in Field's Virology. I didn't find any explanation there of why immune response does not develop.

Comment: Gosh, then I think you should read better sources... It's a really interesting virus, one I've spent a considerable amount of time reading about, and have had several personal encounters with. It's fascinating, really. There is suggestion in the literature that the longest incubation time recorded for the virus is 18 years! Can you imagine how well it hides from the body's immune system? I'd try Google if I didn't know.